# Let $t_n$ be a convergent sequence and suppose that $\lim(t_n)>a$. Prove there exists a number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $t_n>a$.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

My start:
Say $\lim(t_n)=b$ and let $\epsilon>0$.
Then there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|t_n-b|<\epsilon$.

or should I say:

Let $a>0$.
Then there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|t_n-b|<a$.

Am I going in the right direction? Any tips of where to go from here would be helpful.

Comment: Take $\epsilon = \frac{b-a}{2}$. Then $|t_n-b| < \epsilon \implies t_n > a$